# Flatten collection of individual dates into date ranges

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Given a datatable of single day dates (dd-mm-yyyy), (shown below on the left).

What's most elegant way to transform this into a collection of ranges, grouping consecutive days for each type (show on the right) ?

We can assume initial data is sorted by TypeID, then Date.

```
TypeID  | Date            ->   TypeID  | Start      | End
1       | 01/02/2010           1       | 01/02/2010 | 03/02/2010
1       | 02/02/2010           2       | 03/02/2010 | 04/02/2010
1       | 03/02/2010           2       | 06/02/2010 | 06/02/2010
2       | 03/02/2010
2       | 04/02/2010
2       | 06/02/2010
```

I'm not particularity up on my LINQ, but I was thinking that might be the way to go?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how do you determine what the start and end date is?

Comment: @skyfoot start and end date is the beginning and end of any date range found in the initial data.

Comment: But then shouldnt it be  "01/02/2010 to 03/02/2010" and "03/02/2010 to 06/02/2010"

Comment: @skyfoot, looks like it's consecutive days

Comment: @Phil ah yes, sorry I should have perhaps been clearer about that - consecutive days only. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure somebody will come up with a neat LINQ solution but here's my old style solution. Sure it's got problems and won't cope with every combination, cobbled together and solves the problem but not elegant in any way :-(

```
internal class SourceData
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

internal class Result
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

        var a = new List<SourceData> {
            new SourceData {TypeId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 01)},
            new SourceData {TypeId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 02)},
            new SourceData {TypeId = 1, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 03)}, 
            new SourceData {TypeId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 03)}, 
            new SourceData {TypeId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 04)}, 
            new SourceData {TypeId = 2, Date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 06)} 
        };

        var results = new List<Result>();
        int currentTypeId = 1;
        var rangeEndDate = new DateTime();

        DateTime rangeStartDate = a[0].Date;
        DateTime currentDate = a[0].Date;

        for (int i = 1; i < a.Count() ; i++)
        {

            if (a[i].TypeId != currentTypeId)
            {
                results.Add(new Result() { TypeId = currentTypeId, StartDate = rangeStartDate, EndDate = rangeEndDate });
                currentTypeId += 1;                    
                rangeStartDate = a[i].Date;
            }

            TimeSpan tSpan = a[i].Date - currentDate;
            int differenceInDays = tSpan.Days;

            if(differenceInDays > 1)
            {
                results.Add(new Result { TypeId = currentTypeId, StartDate = rangeStartDate, EndDate = a[i-1].Date });
                rangeStartDate = a[i].Date;
            }

            rangeEndDate = a[i].Date;
            currentDate = a[i].Date;
        }

        results.Add(new Result { TypeId = currentTypeId, StartDate = rangeStartDate, EndDate = rangeEndDate });

        Console.WriteLine("Output\n");
        foreach (var r in results)
            Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "{0} - {1} - {2}",r.TypeId,r.StartDate.ToShortDateString(),r.EndDate.ToShortDateString()));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Gives the following output :-

Output

1 - 01/02/2010 - 03/02/2010

2 - 03/02/2010 - 04/02/2010

2 - 06/02/2010 - 06/02/2010

Comment: This is almost the same approach as I'm currently using, it does the job, and it's readable, so don't put yourself down :)

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE** Previous answer removed.

**EDIT** Try this revised one:

```
public static IEnumerable<TAnonymous> Flatten<T, TAnonymous>(
    this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
    Func<T, T, bool> criteria,
    Func<T, T, TAnonymous> selector,
    Func<TAnonymous, T, T, TAnonymous> modifier)
{
    var list = new List<TAnonymous>();

    T last = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    bool created = false;

    TAnonymous current = default(TAnonymous);

    Action<T, T> action = (a, b) =>
                          {
                              if (criteria(a, b)) {
                                  if (created) {
                                      current = modifier(current, a, b);
                                  } else {
                                      current = selector(a, b);
                                      created = true;
                                  }
                              } else {
                                  if (created) {
                                      list.Add(current);
                                      current = default(TAnonymous);
                                      created = false;
                                  } else {
                                      list.Add(selector(a, a));
                                  }
                              }
                          };

    foreach (T item in enumerable) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            last = item;
            continue;
        }

        action(last, item);
        last = item;
    }

    action(last, last);

    if (created)
        list.Add(current);

    return list;
}
```

Called as:

```
var filtered = list.Flatten(
    (r1, r2) => ((r2.Date - r1.Date).Days <= 1 && r1.TypeID == r2.TypeID),
    (r1, r2) => new { r1.TypeID, Start = r1.Date, End = r2.Date },
    (anon, r1, r2) => new { anon.TypeID, anon.Start, End = r2.Date });
```

Should hopefully work... What we are doing this time, is breaking up the operations into stages, first matching a criteria, and then either creating a new item (selector), or updating the previously created item (modifier).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that out, is rather interesting, especially given that I don't know much LINQ! Also, I think this is a slightly more complicated problem than it first appears as you've said. quite fun :)

Comment: There's enough code in there to make your head spin! Seems like a procedural approach might be easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: I agree, to do what he needs, I don't think Linq is really suited.